# Change water color in d3 orthographic transition map

Tags: d3.js, topojson, orthographic

I am new to D3 and this is my first question to stackoverflow.

I am trying to change the color of the water in this example that contains transitions:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330

I am able to change the color in this example, which is static: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757125

I found this thread: [How can I color ocean with topojson in d3 when I have coordinate info for land?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663982/how-can-i-color-ocean-with-topojson-in-d3-when-i-have-coordinate-info-for-land) However, this changes the area outside of the globe as well.

This section of the code appears to be the styling, but I can't figure what to add to change the water color.

```
c.fillStyle = "#bbb", c.beginPath(), path(land), c.fill();
c.fillStyle = "#f00", c.beginPath(), path(countries[i]), c.fill();
c.strokeStyle = "#fff", c.lineWidth = .5, c.beginPath(), path(borders), c.stroke();
c.strokeStyle = "#000", c.lineWidth = 2, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke();
```

Also, seeing the line of code below, I searched online for a reference list of possible topojson features and/or objects that might indicate water, and maybe I could figure out how to style that, but couldn't find one:

`land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land),`

I'm wondering if maybe this has something to do with canvas (which I don't really grasp).

Hopefully, I'm overlooking something obvious and noob-like.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha! Of course:

Modify this line:

```
c.strokeStyle = "#ccc", c.lineWidth = .5 * ratio, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke();
```

To this:

```
c.fillStyle = "#000", c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.fill();
```

I feel silly, but I guess sometimes it takes writing it all out for the brain cells to click. Thanks!